# Eventbrite at-the-door API

Tags: eventbrite

Trying to set up an at-the-door ticketing solution for an upcoming makerfaire. We're contractually obligated to use eventbrite, but really don't want to use their ipad app so I'd like to programatically add an at-the-door cash ticket but don't see how to do that.

Anyone have ideas?

thanks!

--Derek

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this use-case is not available via the API.
You can [manually add attendees using Eventbrite's web-based interface](http://www.eventbrite.com/t/add-attendees).

If you really needed to automate that process, you could try scripting something with selenium / webdriver.